# How to sort an array of n elements using n - 1 threads

Tags: c, multithreading, sorting, unix, pthreads

I have to sort an array of `n` elements using `n - 1` threads. For each thread I test a boolean flags that is equal to 0 is the elements in position `i` and `i+1` have to be swapped, otherwise it will be set to 1. Every thread body is a function that ends only if all the elements are in the right position, that is all the flags are equal to 1.

Following is the main function where I create the threads and join them (some variables are global):

```
int i;
pthread_t threads[n - 1];

// init the array with random values
array = init_array(n);
len = n;

// flags to check if the array is sorted
is_array_sorted = 0;
is_sorted = calloc(n - 1, sizeof(int));

// prints the initial array
print_array(array, n);

// init the mutex
pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL);

// create n - 1 threads
for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
{
    if (pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, swap, (void*)&i) != 0)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

// waits until all threads end
for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
{
    if (pthread_join(threads[i], NULL) != 0)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

// destroy the mutex
pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock);

// prints the sorted array
print_array(array, n);

// free memory
free(array);
free(is_sorted);
```

And this is the thread body function:

```
static void* swap(void* args)
{
    // Indiex of the element to check (j and j+1)
    int j = *((int*)args);

    // while the array is not sorted
    while (1)
    {
        int i;

        // start mutual exclusion
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);

        // check if we have to swap elements
        if (array[j] > array[j+1])
        {
            // swap elements
            int temp = array[j];
            array[j] = array[j + 1];
            array[j + 1] = temp;
        }

        // now the elements in position j and j+1 are in the right order
        is_sorted[j] = 1;
        is_array_sorted = 1;

        // check if all elements are sorted
        for (i = 0; i < len - 1; i++)
        {
            if (is_sorted[i] == 0)
            {
                is_array_sorted = 0;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (is_array_sorted)
        {
            // the array is sorted, terminate the thread
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
            break;
        }

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

The problem is that this program never ends.
Why? How can I fix this problem?

Please note that this is a multithreading exercise where performance, or a best solution is not required.

Comment: How many elements are your sorting? You have implemented at best an O(n*n*n) algorithm. It could be worse if `pthread_mutex_unlock()` isn't a constant time operation. It may never end if `pthread_mutex_unlock()` isn't truly fair. I'm only talking about the algorithm, I haven't looked closely for bugs in your program. I think you should rethink your algorithm, and design a different solution.

Comment: I'm sorting **n** elements. I can't change the algorithm, I have to sort `n` elements using exactly `n - 1` threads.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
{
    if (pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, swap, (void*)&i) != 0)
```

is probably not doing what you think it should be doing. There is only one variable `i`, and you are passing the address to `i` to all your threads. `i` is being incremented each time you launch another thread. There is no guarantee that each thread will see a unique value when they access the data at the passed in address.

A hacky way to deal with this is to pass in a pointer value that corresponds to the integer value you want the thread to receive.

```
char *x = 0;
for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
{
    if (pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, swap, x++) != 0)
```

The thread function could decode it like this:

```
    int j = (char*)args - (char *)0;
```

As I already stated in my comments, your sorting approach is highly undesirable, and should be reworked. I would think that a teacher that would give high marks to this solution does not think very highly of the abilities of the students.